# Poles of the transfer function

Tags: transfer-function

Why are the poles of the transfer function of the sinusoidal input signal always on the left side? I know that it makes the system bounded, but is there a way to understand it conceptually without going through the maths?

Answer (score 3):

The input signal is irrelevant. All the poles of a TF must have a negative real part because each contributes \$e^{\alpha t}\$ to the response, where \$\alpha\$ is the real value of a pole, and \$\alpha\$ must be negative to give a decaying exponential. A positive value means the response goes to infinity.

Comment: thanks, but what about poles that are zero. Doesn't it give a sinusoidal response? Why they are not acceptable? Is it because physically the response should always decay?

Comment: If so how would we explain the steady state sinusoidal response of a system if the response has to decay?

Comment: A pole at zero represents an integrator, which can, arguably, be regarded as unstable since the response to a step input will be a ramp that clearly goes to infinity. However, the response to, say, an impulse is a constant value, which is clearly not infinite. Safest thing to say is that it's marginally stable.

Comment: An imaginary pair of poles, i.e. zero real part, will give a steady state sinusoidal response, \$e^{\pm j \omega t}=cos(\omega t)\pm j\:sin(\omega t)\$

Comment: Well, without doing any maths, the steady state response of a stable, linear system to a sinusoidal input will be sinusoidal. And the output sinusoid will have the same frequency as the input sinusoid.

Comment: well then how come an imaginary poles with zero real parts are not considered and we always say that the poles should be negative? Now I understand that when the poles are positive the system would become unstable and that what makes them unacceptable. But isn't a sinusoidal response an acceptable response and if so why they are not considered and the response should always decay?

Comment: Why would you want an unstable system? Are you confusing the roles of the TF and the input signal? A sinusoid applied to a stable system gives two output components: a transient and a steady sinusoid. The real parts of the TF poles determine how quickly or slowly the transient disappears.

Comment: For example for the case of LC system, H(s) poles should be on imaginary axis. That would be a case that for example the poles are not negative I suppose.

Comment: Luckily all passive parts have a parasitic dissipation so purely imaginary poles won't exist unless 'actively' added.